# Rails-assets with bower.io package is stripping url paths from css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bundler, bower

I am trying to get rails-assets with a bower package running.

My problem is that it replaces all css-url-paths with single dots, e.g.:

the bower package looks like:

`background-image: image-url(img/sprites/mini.png)`

and after I installed it via bundler:

`background-image: image-url(".");`

How can I prevent that? What should I configure to make that work?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out that, yet.

As a workaround I converted all images to [base64](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=image+to+base64). It seams that only paths are stripped.